# Camel Kafka consumer - is it possible to get multiple kafka messages in 1 shot and can manual commit

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

I have a route that listens to Kafka topic and calls a bean that takes in Exchange object containing the Kafka message. If I have 10 Kafka messages, my bean will be called 10 times each time the exchange containing 1 message. This is working fine but I want to process messages in parallel so trying to get all 10 messages in 1 call to the bean.

I tried to use aggregate with GroupedExchangedAggregationStategy and it is working where it will collect all 10 messages and call my bean 1 time afterwards and send in the List. Everything is great BUT I now run into this issue that I cannot MANUAL commit Kafka because when I use .aggregate, the threadId when my bean is called is DIFFERENT,ie. 61 than the threadId Kafka consumer has, ie. 51 and the commit wil result in Kafka Consumer code to throw "KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access" ConcurrentModificationException. Fyi - I get the last exchange from the List and use it to manual commit.

Any suggestion on how to get over this issue or there is a better way to do this?

Comment: I know that Spring-Kafka has a Batch API for this. Haven't seen anyone do it with Camel, but Camel also has Spring integration, so that could be an option, still

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. How would I go about Spring Integration though? Can you share more details?

Comment: Also, read Camel documentation for Aggregate and it stated this: "In order to achieve synchronous aggregration, use an instance of SynchronousExecutorService for the executorService option. The aggregated output will execute in the same thread that called the agregator". I tried this and it's not working, it still creates a different thread to do the aggregation.

Comment: .aggregate(new GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy()).constant(true).executorService(new SynchronousExecutorService()).completionSize(15).completionTimeout(1000L)

Comment: I dont use Camel or Spring regularly, but see https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/4.0.x/spring-boot.html or `BatchMessageListener` in Spring-Kafka https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#message-listeners